# I'm Site Owner - Cannot Delete List Items

Tags: delete

I apologize for the basic question, but I seem to have found myself in trouble trying to help our team by updating our outdated sharepoint site. Working with this site (specifically understanding permission settings) is so frustrating. I am inclined to just wiping my hands from sharepoint and passing the buck onto someone else. I should say that I am not sharepoint saavy. I have been trying to teach myself.

Attached are my site contents. There are two lists that I want to delete (TEST and the Calendar). However, unlike every other list, there is no option to remove the list. I know that I created the lists. However, when I go to view the settings, sharepoint tells me that I don’t have access to this page. I can send requests to access the page, but it will never give me access to view the page. 
Furthermore, I am the site owner with the permission levels: Full Control, Design, Edit, Contribute, Read. 
[image]

All I want to do is delete these two items in this list. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to track down the site collection admin who can then grant you the proper permissions. A few other notes:

- Sending access requests will simply send an email to the person who is assigned that role. However, that person may not work for the company anymore, so your requests might not actually be going anywhere useful.
- I know you said that you're the site onwer, but again, I'd have a site collection admin confirm that.
- Have the SharePoint farm admin create a site collection for you to learn on. A separate site collection will help ensure that you can feel free to do whatever, without impacting any existing processes/functionality

Comment: When I submit an access request for myself, I get a pending request email saying that I am wanting authorization for an item, and I have to allow myself access. Naturally, I always accept. I also experimented and let other site owners give me access each time I request it as well. But each time, the result is the same. 

After I allow access and get a notification saying that my request was authorized, I try to access the list to delete, but when I enter the settings I get a "Sorry, you don't have access to this page". 

Site admin confirmed I was an owner.

Comment: 1. Can the other site admin delete those lists? 2. Navigate to site settings--> site permissions --> check permissions, and enter your username. What permissions does it list that you have? 3. Have another admin who does have delete access to the list check the permissions of the list. It's possible that permissions were customized, and the owners group was removed. (SharePoint allows you to remove your own permissions to a site or list)

Comment: No - other owners cannot delete those two lists either. 

I have been trying to figure this out for a while now, and in doing so created a dummy owner group. So I have 3 different permission levels. The following was confirmed by verifying on other owners computer. 

 
Full Control, Design, Edit, Contribute, Read, Limited Access   
Given directly   
 

Full Control, Limited Access   
Given through the "original owner" group.   
 

Full Control, Design, Edit, Contribute, Read   
Given through the "dummy owner" group.

Comment: Find the farm admin. This person will have full control over absolutely everything, and probably works in the IT dept. Have them review the permissions of the list, as most likely the permissions of the list were customized and the owners group was removed or had their permissions changed (for those specific lists).

Comment: I agree with Mike.  I've inherited a SP deployment - groups with names like 'Owner' have been modified, so the permissions are different and no longer 'Out of the Box' (Incidentally, I view changing an OOTB permission as bad practise).